# Storyboard pass data from view controller to tab bar with segue

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have one page(say X) before tab bar controller that use model segue to open tab bar controller. Also first screen of tab bar controller is same with X.

> I want to pass data from X to tab bar controller's first page.

Shortly, I want to pass data from view controller to tab bar controller page with storyboard segue. Is there any method for this ?

Here is the solution ;

```
    locationsHome* vc = [[locationsHome alloc] init];
    UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc = (locationsHome *)[[tbc customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: It looks like you answered your question. I thought you were asking the more basic question of how to pass data to `segue.destinationViewController`, but I'm glad to see you solved your problem.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Sorry Tiago, I'm newbie on this website. I will do what you suggest and thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. You can pass data from ViewController to TabBarController with this method.

Use this code within `prepareForSegue` method

```
locationsHome* vc = [[locationsHome alloc] init];
UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
vc = (locationsHome *)[[tbc customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Like this:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    NSString * segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
    if([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"tabbarGo"]){

        locationsHome* vc = [[locationsHome alloc] init];
        UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc = (locationsHome *)[[tbc customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        etc...

    }
}
```

Comment: I had added the prepareForSegue method. however i failed to make the navigation work. Any idea why?

Comment: You should use UITabBarController for destination View Controller than you should give the index number.

Answer (score 2):

```
//if sent to First Tab of Tab Bar Controller
UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
createTeamViewController *controller = (createTeamViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

controller.userProfile = self.userProfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the destination view controller (the subclassed tab bar controller) and then in the source view controller, implement [`prepareForSegue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW4) to pass information to the destination controller. You can then have the destination view controller's `viewDidLoad` to act upon the data that was passed to it in the `prepareForSegue` of the source view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 2.2**, I had to modify accepted answer this way

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "userAccountSegue")
    {
        var firstTabViewController: UserAccountViewController = UserAccountViewController()
        let tabViewController: UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        firstTabViewController = (tabViewController.customizableViewControllers![0] as! UserAccountViewController)
        firstTabViewController.userObj = arrayForTable![selectedIndex] as? User

    }
}
```

Note : Hint for above code snip

- **User** is my **Model** object storing user information
- My View controller segue is connected to the TabViewContoller in storyboard with segue = "**userAccountSegue**"